# Real time data plotting from a high throughput source

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot Real time in a way that updates fast.

The data I have:

- arrives via serial port at 62.5 Hz
- data corresponds to 32 sensors (so plot 32 lines vs time).
- 32points *62.5Hz = 2000 points/sec

The problem with my current plotting loop is that it runs slower than 62.5[Hz], meaning **I miss some data** coming in from serial port.

I am looking for any solution to this problem that allows for:

- All data from serial port to be saved.
- Plots the data (even skipping a few points/using averages/eliminating old points and only keeping the most recent)

Here is my code, I am using random data to simulate the serial port data.

```py
import numpy as np 
import time 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#extra plot debugging
hz_ = [] #list of speed
time_=[] #list for time vs Hz plot


 #store all data generated
store_data = np.zeros((1, 33))
 #only data to plot 
to_plot = np.zeros((1, 33)) 
 #color each line 
colours = [f"C{i}" for i in range (1,33)]

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(10,8))
ax.set_xlabel('time(s)')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_ylim([0, 300])
ax.set_xlim([0, 200])

start_time = time.time()
for i in range (100):
    loop_time = time.time()
     #make data with col0=time and col[1:11] = y values
    data = np.random.randint(1,255,(1,32)).astype(float) #simulated data, usually comes in at 62.5 [Hz]
    data =  np.insert(data, 0, time.time()-start_time).reshape(1,33) #adding time for first column
    store_data = np.append(store_data, data , axis=0)
    to_plot = store_data[-100:,]
    
    for i in range(1, to_plot.shape[1]):
        ax.plot(to_plot[:,0], to_plot[:,i],c = colours[i-1], marker=(5, 2), linewidth=0, label=i)
        #ax.lines = ax.lines[-33:] #This soluition speeds it up, to clear old code. 

    fig.canvas.draw()  
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    Hz = 1/(time.time()-loop_time)
     #for time vs Hz plot
    hz_.append(Hz)
    time_.append( time.time()-start_time)
    print(1/(time.time()-loop_time), "Hz - frequncy program loops at")
   
 #extra fig showing how speed drops off vs time
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(10,8))
fig.suptitle('Decreasingn Speed vs Time', fontsize=20)
ax.set_xlabel('time(s)')
ax.set_ylabel('Hz')

ax.plot(time_, hz_)
fig.show()
```

[image]

I also tried while using

```py
ax.lines = ax.lines[-33:]
```

to remove older points, and this speed up the plotting, but still slower than the speed i aquire data.
[image]

Any library/solution to make sure I collect all data and plot the general trendlines (so even not all points) is ok. Maybe something that runs acquiring data and plotting in parallel?

Comment: Are you restricted to Python only, or can you use other languages ?
Because for fast data treatment and GUI display, it might be difficult for Python to do the job.

Comment: I also use matlab here, maybe that is better? or what do you suggest?

Comment: What delay between the data acquisition and the plotting is acceptable for you?

Comment: @norok2 The graph can update even every 2ms or 5[Hz], the issue is that at that speed I lose some data sent via pyserial (it comes in at 62.5[Hz]), or it backlogs and shows a significant delay in my plot.

Comment: so speed > 62.5[Hz] would be ideal. Or some way to run it separate from pyserial so that I am able to do both collect data at 62.5[Hz] and update the plot at even 4 or 5 [Hz]. I cannot change the hardware I am using to acquire the data,  and I believe it must have a buffer since when registering 3-4[Hz] of loop time, my plot has delays of many seconds

Comment: @norok2, delay between data received and data plotted can be even half or 1 second, as long as it stays constant. The data comes in without timestamp, which I attach to it once i receive it, so as long as that remains consistent it is ok to have a delay of half a second.

Comment: If you know how to acquire data fast enough, you can write it to a file, making sure to flush frequently enough (half a sec or so). Then you can use another process to read that file and you plot only the last part at whatever frequency you manage. Matplotlib cannot get much faster than that, but you seems to indicate that is not the main issue.

Comment: this seems like the solution! do you have an example? would I have to run 2 python scripts separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to have two separate processes:

- one for acquiring and storing the data
- one for plotting the data

---

Below there are two basic scripts to get the idea.
You first run `gen.py` which starts to generate numbers and save them in a file.
Then, in the same directory, you can run `plot.py` which will read the last part of the file and will update the a Matplotlib plot.

Here is the `gen.py` script to generate data:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time
import random

LIMIT_TIME = 100  # s
DATA_FILENAME = "data.txt"


def gen_data(filename, limit_time):
    start_time = time.time()
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        while elapsed_time < limit_time:
            f.write(f"{time.time():30.12f} {random.random():30.12f}\n")  # produces 64 bytes
            f.flush()
            elapsed = time.time() - start_time
            

gen_data(DATA_FILENAME, LIMIT_TIME)
```

and here is the `plot.py` script to plot the data (reworked from [this one](https://pythonforundergradengineers.com/live-plotting-with-matplotlib.html)):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import io
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.animation


BUFFER_LEN = 64
DATA_FILENAME = "data.txt"
PLOT_LIMIT = 20
ANIM_FILENAME = "video.gif"


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10,8))
ax.set_title("Plot of random numbers from `gen.py`")
ax.set_xlabel("time / s")
ax.set_ylabel("random number / #")
ax.set_ylim([0, 1])


def get_data(filename, buffer_len, delay=0.0):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        f.seek(0, io.SEEK_END)
        data = f.read(buffer_len)
        if delay:
            time.sleep(delay)
    return data


def animate(i, xs, ys, limit=PLOT_LIMIT, verbose=False):
    # grab the data
    try:
        data = get_data(DATA_FILENAME, BUFFER_LEN)
        if verbose:
            print(data)
        x, y = map(float, data.split())
        if x > xs[-1]:
            # Add x and y to lists
            xs.append(x)
            ys.append(y)
            # Limit x and y lists to 10 items
            xs = xs[-limit:]
            ys = ys[-limit:]
        else:
            print(f"W: {time.time()} :: STALE!")
    except ValueError:
        print(f"W: {time.time()} :: EXCEPTION!")
    else:
        # Draw x and y lists
        ax.clear()
        ax.set_ylim([0, 1])
        ax.plot(xs, ys)


# save video (only to attach here) 
#anim = mpl.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=([time.time()], [None]), interval=1, frames=3 * PLOT_LIMIT, repeat=False)
#anim.save(ANIM_FILENAME, writer='imagemagick', fps=10)
#print(f"I: Saved to `{ANIM_FILENAME}`")

# show interactively
anim = mpl.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=([time.time()], [None]), interval=1)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image: Anim]

Note that I have also included and commented out the portion of code that I used to generate the animated GIF above.

I believe this should be enough to get you going.

Comment: sorry, i geniunly cannot get this to work. The second part of the code always gives "W: 1655886293.2099771 :: EXCEPTION!". I have also tried to combine them with Multiprocessing, is this what you intended?

Comment: @Leo No, you do not need to combine them. You just need to run them separately. Likewise, if you were to follow this approach for your use case, you should have one script capturing the data and saving to disk, and another independent script just for reading the data just saved and plotting them.

Comment: Thanks! it worked. For some reason it works when i run it in pucharm, but not from terminal following these instructions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48648597/how-to-use-batch-file-to-run-multiple-python-scripts-simultaneously, and it gives me: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'", but it works in pycharm so great!

Comment: @Leo you should check which interpreter is used from the terminal and whether it has access to all the modules you need.

Comment: thanks! it was exactly that the interpreter was different, so I disinstalled both python and pycharm. Usually i just program on google COLAB so don't understand virtual enviroments and not finding packages... will deal with it when the program is done. Thank you again